Teradata SQL - How to use the value from previous rows
I am having a rather simple problem, however making it complicated by overthinking. I am hoping someone can help me here.
I am having a data which have a row for each day in a month and data is for n months. Based on the data on each day, I get a daily position. I am calculating the worst position in a month, however want to use this value at point while processing data after 2 months.
i.e. From the daily data, I will have a worst position (max of position value) by end of Jan and want to use this value by starting of March. The position from end of Feb, to be used by starting of April. and so on. I don't have fix number of monthly cycle.
Sample Data
ID      CALENDAR      POSITION    VALUE 
123     2021-01-01    1           10
123     2021-01-02    2           0
....
123     2021-01-31    5           0
123     2021-02-01    5           6
....
123     2021-02-28    5           0
123     2021-03-01    5           20
....
123     2021-03-31    5           0
....

Output
ID      CALENDAR      POSITION    VALUE  WORST_POSITION
123     2021-01-01    1           10     NULL
123     2021-01-02    5           0      NULL
....
123     2021-01-31    2           0      NULL   
123     2021-02-01    5           6      NULL
....
123     2021-02-28    5           0      NULL
123     2021-03-01    5           20     5    --- this is worst from Jan
....
123     2021-03-31    5           0      5
....

Please let me know if anyone have done something like this. I need this to be done dynamically as the daily position has impact as soon as we have previous worst position known.
Please let me know more information. I will really appreciate a help on this one.
I have tried a recursive query which works well to get output from preceding row but not sure how to get n rows dynamically.

A subquery that does something like SELECT TRUNC(calendar + INTERVAL '2' MONTH, 'month') as cal_month, max(position) FROM yourtable GROUP BY cal_month would give you the max position from two months ago for every month. You could join to that from this query to get the worst_position.

Thank you for your response. Position is not a static field and it’s being created on the run time. Position value has dependency on worst position. So need the value at the run time.
